# How to remove sphere in glass reflection?

Tags: glass

I created the “glass” material and a sphere appears in its reflection, which I don’t know how to remove. I'm newcomer to Blender, can someone help me with this? I cant find info on the internet about it.

[image: Render view]

[image: In viewport1]

[image: In viewport2]

[image: Glass settings 1]

[image: Glass settings 2 - with result]

[image: Transparent BSDF - value 0]

[image: if im using Glossy BSDF]

[image: new glass material settings]

[image]

Comment: try to select glass and set Shade Flat from context menu

Comment: @Crantisz 
I entered to Edit mode, selected all edges -> RMB -> Shade Flat
unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Can you share the file? You can use https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @Crantisz
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=gV8YVWqv" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/gV8YVWqv/)

Comment: @Crantisz
I created a new project and made the same glass material. there is a similar problem

Comment: btw, if I increase the value of ior, then the sphere in the reflection becomes smaller, but then the transparency is lost

Comment: @Crantisz wow, you are principal developer at mts digital, I'm just trying to get to your work)) idk can I write here in rus

Comment: It seems a problem from using transparent and transmission at the same time. But I don't have a strong opinion why it is happened and how it can be fixed. So maybe someone else will answer.

Comment: No, it is an international website, but you can join my VK group if you want https://vk.com/blender_3d

Comment: ty @Crantisz, I subscribed)
I found a possible solution: instead of “Glass BSDF” I decided to create through “Glossy BSDF”, also in “Mix Shader” I added the node “Layer weight” with the value “Blend” = 0.3
I added the result above, please evaluate this solution to the issue

Comment: behind the top right glass (between the door and the wall) I added a red object to check the transparency of the glass, the object itself is visible, but the color is rendered black (probably due to the lack of lighting)

Comment: I want to add that you may need to Pack Resource Files and forward your blend file again. The image you used in your world property(quarry_4_pure_sky) is missing.

Comment: @OgunlesiTaiwo
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=WLNxxMXL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/WLNxxMXL/)